# install openstack magnum on docker

Tags: docker, openstack

I installed openstack magnum (ocata release) on docker in my controller node because I have installed newton on my host machines and newton binaries did not install correctly but now when I try to run magnum-service list command the output is:

```
ERROR: Unable to establish connection to http://controller:9511/v1/mservices
```

then I checked both magnum-api and magnum-conductor logs and there was an error:

```
ERROR magnum ImportError: No module named profiler
```

then I tried:

```
su -s /bin/sh -c "/var/lib/magnum/env/bin/pip install profiler" magnum
```

but even after installing profiler the error was the same.
Can anyone help?

Tnx to @eandersson now both services are running successfully but I faced another problem and that is when I try to run:

```
magnum service-list
```

The result is:

```
ERROR: 'errors'
```

So I tried:

```
magnum --debug service-list
```

And the result was:

```
ERROR: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace' (HTTP 500) (Request-ID: req-cbe3a389-1cea-49f6-8472-3275696a67e3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably missing [osprofiler](https://github.com/openstack/magnum/blob/f0dec728e78bcb3851b1a484b73bfe567b3c1fc9/magnum/common/profiler.py#L27), not profiler

```
profiler = importutils.try_import("osprofiler.profiler")
profiler_initializer = importutils.try_import("osprofiler.initializer")
profiler_web = importutils.try_import("osprofiler.web")
```

Try installing it instead.

> su -s /bin/sh -c "/var/lib/magnum/env/bin/pip install osprofiler" magnum

By the way, when pip installing something for OpenStack you should be applying the requirements constrains.

> -c https://git.openstack.org/cgit/openstack/requirements/plain/upper-constraints.txt?h=stable/ocata

So ideally your command would look like this.

> su -s /bin/sh -c "/var/lib/magnum/env/bin/pip install -c https://git.openstack.org/cgit/openstack/requirements/plain/upper-constraints.txt?h=stable/ocata osprofiler" magnum

Comment: Tnx now services are running but as I said in my recent edit I faced another error.
can you help me with that too?